# Add parameters to intent on launch

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm pretty sure there was a way to add parameters to intent on launch of app from android studio (simulate opened from push notification).

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. It is completely possible. If you check the [`am` command](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am)'s help, you will see that we can pass arguments using `-e`.

[image]

So, follow these steps:

**1.** Edit launch configurations:

[image]

**2.** Add the desired arguments in the `Launch Flags` box, then press `Apply` and `OK`:

[image]

**3.** Now the passing argument will be available in the launcher activity's extras:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you handle the intent yourself.

In this case it's always possible to add an Extra to an Intent, as long as the object you try to pass a parameter is either implements Parcelable or Serializable.

So your process could look like:

In the activity starting class

```
Intent launch = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
launch.putExtra("parcelable", new ParcelableObject());
startActivity(launch);
```

In the new activity

```
Intent from = getIntent();
ParcelableObject pojo = from.getParcelableExtra("parcelable");
```

Comment: not what i was looking for. I wanted to add those parameters somewhere in the run configuration of android studio. nothing in code